# Erro ao utiizar Sound Exchange (Sox)

Tags: node.js, windows, reconhecimento-de-voz

Estou tentando utilizar a API Goggle Speech-to-text em node.js, mas quando eu tento rodar o serviço eu encontro o erro:

[image: Erro SoX]

Meu ambiente de desenvolvimento **no trabalho** hoje é Windows 7, contudo já consegui fazer rodar no Ubuntu (mas ainda preciso fazer isso no W7). A documentação do SoX pede para que eu baixe os binários e adicione ele no $PATH, conforme fiz abaixo:

[image: print path]

Segue a documentação do Google-Speech-to-text que estou seguindo:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize?hl=pt-br

Site para instalação do Sox: http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Acredito que o problema está no sox por causa do log e por que esse mesmo código rodou em ambiente Ubuntu. Será que estou fazendo a instalação de maneira equivocada, ou é algo do ambiente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema. De alguma maneira a instalação dos binários realizada pela documentação parece estar depreciada. Felizmente encontrei uma ferramenta que faz a instalação desses binários:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/sox.portable#individual

Instalando o gerenciador de pacotes do chocolatey vocês conseguiram baixar pacotes via terminal igual é feito com o aptitude no linux (atentem-se apenas em executar o cmd como administrador - pode ser necessário utilizar o PowerShell do windows para utilizar o Chocolatey).